# Undesired results when using .sample() with .where() in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to select 2 random values from a dataframe where a condition is met.
Please ee example df below:

```
data = {'col1':  ['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx','yz'],
        'col2': ['4', '1','4','4','0','1','4','2','4'],
        'col3': ['Sweden', 'Malaysia','Sweden','Venezuela','France','Sweden','Australia','Belgium','Sweden']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
```

I want to select 2 random values from 'col1' where 'col2' is equal to 4. The code I then use is:

```
print(df['col1'].sample(n=2).where(df['col2']==4))
```

With the desired output being:

```
0  abc
6  stu
```

....or

```
8  yz
2 ghi
```

However the code currently gives outputs such as:

```
7    NaN
3    NaN
```

This is undesirable in that a) I'm expecting to see a string value as text and b) whilst the value correspoding to row 3 would meet the criteria, the value corresponding to row 7 does not, so the criteria is not being met in all cases.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How would I modify my code such that it returns text values and only in the case where the condition is met
2. How would I add a second condition eg `.where(df['col2']==4) & (df['col3']=='Sweden')`

Grateful for any guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to filter your data first. I am not sure if you specifically want to use `.where()` but if not, this will also help with your next step of adding more criteria.

Also, I think part of your problem is that in your df, col2 values are strings, so you need to have your formula find '4' instead of the number 4.

```
df.loc[df['col2'] == '4','col1'].sample(n=2)
```

Comment: For the additional condition I will use the following code:

`df.loc[(df['col2'] == '4') & (df['col3'] == 'Sweden'),'col1'].sample(n=2)`